# Checkstyle not generating reports with Maven, but showing issues while in Eclipse any hints?

Tags: maven, checkstyle

`checkstyle.xml` looks like

```
<property name="severity" value="warning"/>

<property name="fileExtensions" value="java, properties, xml"/>
  <module name="TreeWalker">
    <property name="tabWidth" value="4"/>
    <module name="JavadocMethod">
        <property name="scope" value="public"/>
        <property name="allowMissingParamTags" value="true"/>
        <property name="allowMissingThrowsTags" value="true"/>
        <property name="allowMissingReturnTag" value="true"/>
        <property name="minLineCount" value="2"/>
        <property name="allowedAnnotations" value="Override, Test"/>
        <property name="allowThrowsTagsForSubclasses" value="true"/>
    </module>
    <module name="JavadocVariable">
        <property name="scope" value="protected"/>
    </module>
    <module name="AvoidStarImport"/>
</module>
```

`pom.xml` looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>my-group</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-tests</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>my-tests</name>
    <description>my-tests</description>
    <properties>
        <checkstyle.config.location>checkstyle.xml</checkstyle.config.location>
    </properties>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>checkstyle-profile</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.17</version>
                        <configuration>

                            <configLocation>checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>checkstyle-check</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>check</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <phase>test</phase> 
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

    </profiles>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.8.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.17</version>
                <configuration>
                    <configLocation>checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
                </configuration>
                <reportSets>
                    <reportSet>
                        <reports>
                            <report>checkstyle</report>
                        </reports>
                    </reportSet>
                </reportSets>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
</project>
```

If I run Checkstyle in Eclipse, it shows me errors. But on command line, the Checkstyle report is not not generated. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

By default Maven Checkstyle Plugin reports only violations on `error` level. In your `checkstyle.xml` you have declared that all checks will report problems on `warning` level and that's why you don't see any output.

You can either declare [severity](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config.html#Properties) of all checks to `error` in `checkstyle.xml`:

```
<property name="severity" value="warning"/>
```

or change [violationSeverity](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/check-mojo.html#violationSeverity) in `pom.xml`:

```
<configuration>
    <violationSeverity>warning</violationSeverity>
    <configLocation>checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
</configuration>
```